# SQL Server - OPENJSON output with an explicit schema

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I have the below array of an HTTP request, in `JSON` format:

```
[
    {
        "Code":"856956645",
        "Type":"Colet",
        "MeasuredWeight":0.0,
        "VolumetricWeight":0.0,
        "ConfirmationName":null,
        "Observation":" 100 DE SFATURI OASELE",
        "ResponseCode":null,
        "Event":
            [   
                {
                    "Date":"2018-11-16T16:22:29.397",
                    "EventId":73,
                    "Description":"Ridicare din comanda client",
                    "LocalityName":"BUCURESTI"
                },
                {
                    "Date":"2018-11-17T08:55:06.14",
                    "EventId":5,
                    "Description":"Spre destinatar ",
                    "LocalityName":"BUCURESTI"
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

How could I extract the value of `Description` element, within the second set of values. I tried with `OPENJSON` but I couldn't do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (
            Description nvarchar(100) '$.Event.Description'
);
```

Comment: *"I couldn't do it"* doesn't tell us anything I'm afraid; what was the problem you had? Was it something along the lines of `Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 29 JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 349.`? If so, the error is telling you the problem here; your JSON isn't valid JSON (and you need to fix it).

Comment: No, it's not this. I get `NULL`

Comment: Then can you provide valid JSON please so that we know that isn't the issue (as it's not right now).

Comment: I just edited the code, a pair of double quotes was misplaced. Try again please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nesting instead. Nor sure why your attempt didn't work; I've not had much use for `OPENJSON` as yet apart from when playing around, however, this works:

```
SELECT J.Code, J.[Type], E.[Description]
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (Code bigint '$.Code',
      [Type] varchar(10) '$.Type',
      [Event] nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) J
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Event])
     WITH ([Description] varchar(100) '$.Description',
           EventID int '$.EventId') E
WHERE E.EventID = 5;
```

*Edit: Worked out why your attempt wasn't working. The JSON you have has a new JSON object in the `Event` node, they're not simply properties, like in the documentation's second example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#path). The entities are wrapped in further brackets (`[]`), not just braces (`{}`), and hence why you have to parse the next layer again as a separate JSON object.*

Comment: This works, but it returns both descriptions and I need only the 2nd.

Comment: @MihailCodrin then add a `WHERE`.